# Loop without Do error

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA.  I am trying to copy cells from one workbook to another.  In some cases, the "sending" workbook file will only have 1 row to copy over, and in other cases, it may have multiple rows that I want to copy.  This currently works with just 1 row at a time.  I tried adding a Do until, but keep getting a compile error "loop without do"  and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. In my "sending" worksheet, I begin sending from cell H4 and when column H, row x is blank, I want to exit the loop.  Hope that makes sense Thanks!!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim RowNumber As Single
    Dim QuestionID As String
    Dim Question As String
    Dim TotalResponses As Single
    Dim StronglyAgree As Single
    Dim Agree As Single
    Dim NA As Single
    Dim Disagree As Single
    Dim StronglyDisagree As Single
    Dim Total As Single
    Dim RecordID As String
    Dim MATSEvalSummary As Workbook

    RowNumber = 4

    Worksheets("Data for MATS Summary File").Select

    Do Until Cells.Item("H" & RowNumber) = ""

      QuestionID = Range("H" & RowNumber)
      Question = Range("I" & RowNumber)
      TotalResponses = Range("j" & RowNumber)
      StronglyAgree = Range("k" & RowNumber)
      Agree = Range("l" & RowNumber)
      NA = Range("m" & RowNumber)
      Disagree = Range("n" & RowNumber)
      StronglyDisagree = Range("O" & RowNumber)
      Total = Range("P" & RowNumber)
      RecordID = Range("u" & RowNumber)

      Set MATSEvalSummary = Workbooks.Open("C:\MATS Eval Summary\170910 MATS Evals Summary.xlsx")
      Worksheets("sheet1").Select
      Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Select
      RowCount = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

      .Offset(RowCount, 0) = QuestionID
      .Offset(RowCount, 1) = Question
      .Offset(RowCount, 2) = TotalResponses
      .Offset(RowCount, 3) = StronglyAgree
      .Offset(RowCount, 4) = Agree
      .Offset(RowCount, 5) = NA
      .Offset(RowCount, 6) = Disagree
      .Offset(RowCount, 7) = StronglyDisagree
      .Offset(RowCount, 8) = Total
      .Offset(RowCount, 9) = RecordID

     RowNumber = RowNumber + 1

    Loop

     End With
    MATSEvalSummary.Save

    End Sub
```

Comment: `End With` needs to be before `Loop`.  Opening the workbook once - out side the loop - seems a better approach.

Comment: THank you Alex K.  but when I move the "end with" before the "loop", I then get a compile error: "end with without with".

Comment: are you moving the ```End With``` to before ```RowNumber = RowNumber + 1```?

Answer (score 0):

Does the u in `RecordID = Range("u" & RowNumber)` need to be q?

```
Sub test()
    'Variable Declaration
    Dim LastRowWithContent As Integer
    Dim Wb As Workbook

    'Inializing
    Wb = Workbook.Name("WorkbookName")

    'Testing for content
    If Cells(4, 8) <> "" Then
        'Finding the last lowest row in column H with a value
        LastRowWithContent = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
        'copying the contents                           pasting/Destination
        Range("H4", Cells(LastRowWithContent, 16)).Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:I1")
        Range("U4", Cells(LastRowWithContent, 21)).Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J1")
    End If
End Sub
```

If this code doesn't solve what you're looking to complete, I hope it will at least provide you with the tools and knowledge to form it to how you need it.